# Windows Powershell: can I split a large SQL file into small files containing one db object

Tags: windows, powershell

We are using ERWin for data modeling and it generates a large SQL DDL files for all database objects, such as tables and views.  I am thinking to break this big file up into small ones, each containing one table, one view, for instance.

The goal is to reduce the manual work when deploying SQL DDLs with copy/paste each table into an execution windows because in development, usually only a few tables get changed.

I see that each SQL ends with a semi-colon, ";" so I hope there is a way in PowerShell to find this delimiter and separate the large SQL file into many small ones.

Greatly appreciate your help!

Here is one sample SQL code with two tables.

```
CREATE SET  TABLE TABLE_1,
    NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
    NO AFTER JOURNAL,
    NO FALLBACK,
    CHECKSUM = DEFAULT
(

    CAT_ID           INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    CAT_SECTION_ID   INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    CREATE_DTTM          TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL ,
    UPDATE_DTTM          TIMESTAMP(6) NULL 
)
     UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX UPI_CAT_SECTION
     (
            CAT_ID,
            CAT_SECTION_ID
     );

CREATE SET  TABLE TABLE_2,
    NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
    NO AFTER JOURNAL,
    NO FALLBACK,
    CHECKSUM = DEFAULT
(

    CH_NUM          VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL ,
    CH_YEAR   SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
    CREATE_DTTM          TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL ,
    LAST_UPDATE_DTTM     TIMESTAMP(6) NULL 
)
     UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX UPI_TABLE_2
     (
            CH_NUM,
            CH_YEAR,
                 );
```

Comment: "because in development, usually only a few tables get changed" I suggest you use a tool that can build 'differential' scripts, like the one included in Visual Studio (schema compare). Then it only generates the script you need to synchronise databases and you don't need all this manual work to get things aligned. You might need to explain your entire deployment / build process in some more detail.

Comment: This can be achieved using powershell but I cant give examples with out sample data. You should be able to just use $Query.Split(";")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a script that will split your large file into smaller files, starting a new file after each line that contains a semi-colon.  It generates the filename based on the first non-blank line following the semicolon (in your example, the two filenames would be **CREATE_SET_TABLE_CATALOG.SQL** and **CREATE_SET_TABLE_CHASSIS.SQL**.

```
$buffer = @()
$filename = $null
Get-Content '.\LARGEFILE.SQL' | ForEach-Object {
    $line = $_
    $buffer += @($line)

    if ([String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($filename)) {
        $filename = $line.Trim().Replace(',','') -replace '[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]+', '_'
    }

    if ($line.Contains(';')) {
        $buffer | Out-File "$filename.SQL" -Encoding utf8
        $buffer = @()
        $filename = $null
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect.  Next feature I will add myself is to remove the "create set table" from the file names so that I can easily sort all SQL scripts by table names.   Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

If you are just wanting to split the text up into chunks that are cleanly delimited by semi-colons, Nick's recommendation will work.
     $Query.Split(";")

http://ss64.com/ps/split.html

You could roll your own comparison tool from the split up script, but it may be simpler to just use NotePadd++'s compare tool to compare the last deploy to the new code.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-compare/